# Show SearchView underline in Toolbar on API 23+

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-search

My SearchView edit text is not showing any underline. How do I show edit text underline of AppCompat `SearchView`. I have tried this

```
((View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
        .getParent()).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable. abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha);
```

and this

```
searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text)
        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable. abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha);
```

Also tried these in `styles.xml`

```
<item name="queryBackground">@drawable/abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
```

None of them are working. Any pointers?